# How to generate random numbers with arc4random?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, arc4random

I'm trying to generate random numbers from -50 to 50, but I don't know how to accomplish this task using arc4random.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Just as an FYI, using `arc4random` for this won't generate uniformly random numbers (because of how modulus works). Use `arc4random_uniform` instead if that's a concern for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a random number up to 100 and substract 50. You will also need to cast it back to int, since arc4random its an unsigned type.

```
(arc4random() % (101)) - 50
```

Comment: it will generate number b/w `-50 to 49`